# Scroll bar of PagedListView from left side to right side of content in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-pagedlistview

How to move Scroll bar including page up and page down arrows  of android  [PagedListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/widget/PagedListView) from left side to right side of the content. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using an RTL layout?

Comment: @TheWanderer No RTL layout. I am showing number of items in my PagedListView and I want the page up and page down arrows to be moved to Right side.

Comment: You said in your question you wanted them on the right. You also said scrollbar, not paging arrows. Which is it?

Comment: @TheWanderer Yes I want to move the scrollbar including page up and page down arrows  to be moved to Right side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why this isn't documented, but it looks like [you can specify the side in XML](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/91327071443d4a9ce5a8d384864d7af89492aadb/car/core/src/main/java/androidx/car/widget/PagedListView.java#L347).

Sample:

```
<androidx.car.widget.PagedListView
    android:id="@+id/whatever"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:scrollBarGravity="right"
/>
```

This might not work, since I don't actually see the scrollbar's LayoutParams being set after they're changed. In case it doesn't, you can do this yourself in Java with some reflection:

```
Field mScrollBarViewField = PagedListView.class.getDeclaredField("mScrollBarView");
mScrollBarViewField.setAccessible(true);
PagedScrollBarView mScrollBarView = (PagedScrollBarView) mScrollBarViewField.get(pagedListViewInstance);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mScrollBarView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
mScrollBarView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```